# Opening DatePicker in EditText click not showing at first click

Tags: java, android, datepicker, android-edittext

I'm struggling with opening a `DatePicker` while click on a `EditText` . It opens the date picker at the second click only. I have checked with the following options but nothing worked. I have given my code with XML here Kindly suggest me a solution for this problem. Almost i'm trying for the most.

```
<---XML content--->
<EditText
      android:id="@+id/p_date_edt"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"                                
      android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_10dp"
      android:ems="8"
      android:hint="@string/dateTime"
      android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />
```

And my java code is here:

```
pDateEdt = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.p_date_edt);
pDateEdt.setFocusable(false);
pDateEdt.setOnClickListener(this);
      ----

pDateEdt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           datePicker();

       }
});
```

Comment: Me too having the same problem.

Comment: Though switching to an onTouchListener will work, the right way for this is to use a button, and style it to look like an editText.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this it will works on **single click on edittext**

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DatePickerDialog mDatePickerDialog;
    private EditText edDate;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        edDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.activity_ed_date);

        setDateTimeField();
        edDate.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                mDatePickerDialog.show();
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    private void setDateTimeField() {

        Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        mDatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                SimpleDateFormat sd = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                final Date startDate = newDate.getTime();
                String fdate = sd.format(startDate);

                edDate.setText(fdate);

            }
        }, newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        mDatePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());

    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.demoapp.MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/activity_ed_date"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:hint="Date"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:maxLength="30" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Please use `setOnTouchListener` instead of `setOnClickListener`. 
Please use this below code :

```
pDateEdt.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                switch (event.getAction()){
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                         datePicker();

                        break;
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
```

and please Remove this line of code :

```
pDateEdt.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Answer (score 3):

`EditText` does not listen to `OnClickListener`, instead use `OnTouchListener`, it will work.

```
pDateEdt.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {                
        datePicker();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Or, if you want to use `OnClickListener`, use the following method:

```
<EditText
    android:text="@+id/EditText01"
    android:id="@+id/EditText01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />
```

Comment: just  android:focusableInTouchMode="false", worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I have seen a lot of programmers struggling to achieve this feature as your are trying.
Now in your scenario what is happening is when you touch Edittext for the first time, the edittext will get into focus mode, and when you touch the same edittext for second time then only the method in the onClick i.e. datePicker() will execute.
So what you are supposed to do is just remove the `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` tag
and in place of this tag just add the tag `android:focusable="false"`
and in your java code just do the following

```
pDateEdt = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.p_date_edt);
pDateEdt.setOnClickListener(this);
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    datePicker();
}
```

i hope your code will work fine and will let the Date Picker open on your first touch.

Answer (score 0):

Its the most simplest way to work with date picker. Just add two variable

```
private DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog;
EditText etJoiningDate;

etJoiningDate=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etJoiningDate);

    etJoiningDate.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            switch (event.getAction()){
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                    final Calendar cldr = Calendar.getInstance();
                    int day = cldr.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                    int month = cldr.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                    int year = cldr.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                    // date picker dialog
                    datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(TestActivity.this,
                            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                                    etJoiningDate.setText(dayOfMonth + "/" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + year);
                                }
                            }, year, month, day);
                    datePickerDialog.show();

                    break;
            }


            return false;
        }


    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the Best and easiest way to solve this problem:

In the layout file, set these attributes for the EditText

```
android:clickable="true"
android:longClickable="false"
android:focusable="false"
```